# For the S2-LP, what is the frequency format for the function SIGFOX_API_start_continuous_transmission(frequency, mode)

Tags: firmware

Sigfox_CLI_Demo_Project allows a continuous wave mode transmission for test and there is a CLI command start_continuous_transmission in the command table. However, I don't know how to input the frequency.

I have tried to put frequency = 920800000 for 920.8Mhz but get an error 0x0058.  I also tried "RC4" but also get the same err code.

```
    { "start_continuous_transmission",SIGFOX_API_start_continuous_transmission_Action, "wu", ""}, \

    void SIGFOX_API_start_continuous_transmission_Action(void)
    {
      sfx_u32 frequency=(uint32_t)920800000;//(uint32_t)unsignedCommandArgument(0);

    sfx_modulation_type_t mode=(sfx_modulation_type_t)0;//unsignedCommandArgument(1);

    sfx_error_t err;

      err=SIGFOX_API_start_continuous_transmission(frequency, mode);

      responsePrintf("{&N API call...&tx}\r\n",
         "SIGFOX_API_start_continuous_transmission", "sfx_error", err);
    }
```

I get an err 0x0058.

Please help. Thank you !!!!

Answer (score 0):

close the sigfox library first e.g. node_close